# npm install -g is installing to a local folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have been using node and npm for a while, and I just started a larger scale project using it. Recently, however, whenever I run `sudo npm install -g`, it will install it into a `~/Programming/usr/local/bin` instead of `/usr/local/bin`. Does anyone know why this is happening? How can I reset the installation location

Comment: What path do you get when you run `npm config get prefix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the location by running the following command.

`npm config set prefix /usr/local`